# Next.js with dynamic components from page in layout

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a layout using Page.getLayout function with Next.js,

The problem is I want some page specific "slots" in the layout.

I've tried doing this:

```
function TestPage(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        QWe
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

TestPage.getLayout = (page) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <AuthLayout
      header={
        <Header 
          flowTitle="Contacts" 
          pageTitle="All Content"
          pageLeft={<Button onClick={() => router.back()}>All Policies</Button>}
          pageRight={<Button variant="outlined">Request Improvement</Button>}
        />
      }
    >
      {page}
    </AuthLayout>
  )
}

export default TestPage
```

but you cant use hooks in getLayout. I could work around this by creating a separate component, say TestPageHeader.
This leaves me with the problem where I have 2 separate components that might need to talk to each other.

My initial idea was to setup the page like this:

````
  return (
    <>
      <Header [header props here] />
      <Box>
        QWe
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}```

Then I was going to try to extract the "Header" component in the layout from the other children and inject it somehow into the real header, then render the remaining children in the body.

This would be ideal as it would let the header easily communicate with the page, but I couldn't work out how to do this either.

Any one have any way I could get this working? without needing 2 separate components is ideal.
````